hide chrome autofill in reactjs
i have an autocomplete (am using material-ui 5), i want to hide suggestion popper displayed by the browser, how i can get this ?
i tried ,
<MUIAutocomplete
        forcePopupIcon={forcePopupIcon}
        sx={styles.autocomplete}
        renderInput={params => <TextFieldMui
        {...params}
        autoComplete="new-password"
        inputProps={{
            autoComplete: 'new-password',
        }}
        InputProps={{
            inputComponent: cleave ? MaskedTextField : "input",
            ...InputProps,
            inputProps: {
                ...(cleave ? { cleaveOptions } : {}),
                ...inputProps
            }
        }}
        label={showOptional ? isOptionalLabel(label) : label}
    />}
        popupIcon={<Icon fontSize="medium" icon={faChevronDown} />}
        {...rest}
    />

but i still have the same issue.


According to
[MDN web docs][1]. you can control auto-fill behavior by adding autocomplete="off" as an attribute to specific input element or to the entire form.
let me know if you have further question.
